# How to retrive data from mysql to wysiwyg editor using php

Tags: php, mysql, wysiwyg

I am creating a job website in which I am using WYSIWYG editor to post details of a job into HTML format using WYSIWYG editor. 
I am successful in posting job but when I retrieve the same data to update in WYSIWYG editor it does not display in the proper format? How can I do this please help me I am in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

try `html_entity_decode($content)` if it's not working can you post me the content format loaded when load update window or did you check how the content was saved in DB? I think the content was saved with html_encoded for the security if that's is the case you have to do html_decode using above function.